# Changing creating div's to loop, each having unique id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fully working code for divs which are 5x5 boxes. However, instead of writing 25 divs, I want to implement it using 2 for loops. I tried couple of things but couldn't sort it out because I need to have unique id's for each (as you can see in the code). Also different random class names for each like (box1,box2,box3,box4,box5) I have 5 different class because I have different animation order for each. Need help in this issue. I checked almost every topic.

Edit, I should have 2 for loops, one for row one for column.
Below code is my try.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<5; j++) 
    {   

        document.write('<div class="box2" id=1>'
                        +'<script> randomColorGenerator();'
                        + '</'+ 'script> </div>');

    }

}

    <div class="box" id="1" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box3" id="2" > 
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box4" id="3" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="4" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box5" id="5" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="box2" id="6"> 
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="7"> 
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box5" id="8" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box4" id="9">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box3" id="10">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="box5" id="11">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box4" id="12" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box3" id="13">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="14" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="15" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="box" id="16">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box5" id="17" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box3" id="18" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="19" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box4" id="20" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="box3" id="21">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box4" id="22" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="23">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="24" >
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="box5" id="25">
    <script>
    randomColorGenerator();
    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Please show us your best effort, and explain in what way that effort fails, what does it *not* do? What does it do that it should not do? Please take a look at the "*[MCVE]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines to see what we expect you to include in your question, and to explain to you how to ask good questions that improve the odds of your getting a better, more complete answer from which you might learn more usefully.

Comment: You need a preprocessor or a templating engine that will output 25 divs from a `for` loop, like for instance PHP, Jade or Angular (ng-repeat). And call 25 times the same function. The function calls do not need to be right after each div.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down, first off make a function that will generate a div for you.

```
function createDiv(index) {
  var animationClass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  var div = document.createElement('DIV');
  div.class = 'box' + animationClass;
  div.id = index;
  return div;
}
```

Next loop the as many times as you want and add the divs to a container element.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

for (var i=0; i <= 25; i++){
  container.appendChild(createDiv(i));
}
```

Note that for this to work, you need to have an element with an `id` of `container`.

Comment: Seems perfect but i should have 2 for loops, because one for the row one for the column for 5x5 boxes i should have 2 for loops counting to 5

Comment: I'm sorry, why do you want 2 for loops?

Comment: because one for the row one for the column for 5x5 boxes i should have 2 for loops counting to 5

Comment: You're not setting anything to describe rows or columns though, so there really is no need for two loops. Could you post what went wrong with the code?

Comment: It just don't shows anything.I am so new to javascript and css so I don't whats wrong. Also I added innerhtml for the div for adding the function randomColorGenerator();

Comment: You want to insert the clearing div after 5 div elements, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    var id = i % 5;
    var cssClass = 'box' + id;
    var divID = 'div'+i;
    console.log(i + ' id='+id+', divId=' + divID + ', cssClass=' + cssClass);
    if(id == 0) {
       console.log('INSERT CLEAR DIV HERE');
    }
}
```